# Android and AsyncTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm working on app that works with a server alot.
Just rest api requests from my server + some data from Google API's.

I'm using AsyncTasks alot. I have one activity where I have total of 10 AsyncTasks. I don't call them all at once and just call one of each once in a while. I'm also using google places autocomplete API. For some reason (I probably added something) now my requests are all hanging somewhere before they work.

I noticed a weird thing in my logs >> 1 **W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.742ms**
Not sure if that's related but I have no clue as to why all my tasks started to hang up there.

Any ideas/ suggestions are highly appreciated..

Comment: Look into Android Volley library. It will make your life lot easier.

Comment: What do you mean of hanging. is it mean it causing effect on UI thread or it keeps running in background or something else? can you please clear it.

Comment: ok, so i have autocomplete field that is populated once user starts typing. It is synched with google places autocomlete. Once user selects an item i do an api call to my server. (post request) What i'm seeing is that the api for google autocomlete took 3 minutes to get back alife

03-10 00:04:29.799  23093-23093/com.myapp D/myapp: GetPlaces onPreExecute

03-10 00:06:27.013  23093-23872/com.myapp D/myapp: GetPlaces doInBackground

Comment: I just found this article and will try to do as described in-there.. move my asyncTasks off from activity class  
http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/